# Clear memory in NSManagedContext (release memory after creating)

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, out-of-memory, nsmanagedobject

I was not able to find satisfying answer to this question so writing a new question.

When my app starts the first time i need to fill data into coredata DB and the size is very big (around 10mb), there are multiple files and all needs to be inserted into the coredata.

now my problem is i am getting memory warning after processing 4or5 MB. the entities that are created seems to be still alive and i want to clear them as soon as a chunk of data is completed (since it is multiple files i can clear after each file).

this issue is not allowing me to complete process and it always crashes due to memory overload.

I am using iPad mini and latest xcode and ARC.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Core Data manages the memory used by the object graph by using a concept called "faulting". Your application is in complete control of what is faulted and what is not. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Answer (score 0):

First delete all objects before loading your page. After deleting insert your data of all objects in your core data.

```
- (void) deleteAllObjects: (NSString *) entityDescription  {


    LoginAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription
                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
       [managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
       //NSLog(@"%@ object deleted",entityDescription);
    }
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
       //NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",entityDescription,error);
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{

   [self deleteAllObjects:@"Data"];
   //do ur code
   [self insertYourData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create a temporary context, insert some part of data (maybe one entity only) and then save it, set it to nil and create another one? Or you could try to use "reset" method, I never tried it, but as I understand it makes context "forget" all objects, so it should work like deallocating them.

Comment: I tried them but it did not seem to clear memory, so i solved it by enclosing the snippet in autorelease block. this now clears the memory immediately after exiting the block.